# Removing an item from a session

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am storing an item in an asp.net session for example but I do not how to remove such an item can I just do the following. How would i also find the key to ensure it existed to be able to remove it in first place.

```
public void SetObjectValue(string name, object newValue) {
        Session["TestItem"] = newValue;
}
```

Remove

```
public void RemoveObjectValue(string name, object newValue) {
        Session["TestItem"] = null;
}
```

But the key would still be in the Session object how do I remove the test item from the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `.Remove(string name)` method for that. You can see the [MSDN docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.remove?view=netframework-4.8)

Basically, all you have to do is:

```
Session.Remove("TestItem");
```